# is there any code for merging two nested dictionary values in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have nested dictionaries and want to get merged values

```
d1=dict() 
d2=dict() 
d1 = {1: {'x1':('y1')}, 2: 'y1'} 
d2 = {1: {'x1':('y3')}, 2: 'y2'}
```

I want result in the following way:

```
'x1':('y1','y3') ('y1','y2')
```

but find the result

```
({'x1': 'y1'}, {'x1': 'y3'}) ('y1', 'y2')
```

How to get the expected result?

Comment: Please note, as written you desired output is not a valid python format.  It should be either ```[{'x1':('y1', 'y3') }, ('y1', 'y2')]``` or ```({'x1':('y1', 'y3') }, ('y1', 'y2'))``` or possibly ```{'x1'::('y1', 'y3'),  2:('y1', 'y2')}```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by checking values while merging if they are nested dictionaries merge them using the recurrent call for same function as following:

```
mergeTwoDic(d1[key],d2[key]) if isinstance(d1[key],dict) and isinstance(d2[key],dict) else (d1[key],d2[key])
```

so final solution will be as following

```
d1=dict() 
d2=dict() 
d1 = {1: {'x1':('y1')}, 2: 'y1'} 
d2 = {1: {'x1':('y3')}, 2: 'y2'}

def mergeTwoDic (d1,d2):
    result = {};
    for key in d1.keys() | d2.keys():
        if key in d1 and key in d2:
            result[key] = mergeTwoDic(d1[key],d2[key]) if isinstance(d1[key],dict) and isinstance(d2[key],dict) else (d1[key],d2[key])
        else:
            result[key] = d1.get(key) or d2.get(key)

    return result



print(mergeTwoDic(d1,d2).values())
```

output:

```
[{'x1': ('y1', 'y3')}, ('y1', 'y2')]
```